# Build error integrating Clevertap to a Reactnative Application

Tags: objective-c, react-native, cocoapods, clevertap

I'm trying to integrate clevertap with native react and when I include "use_frameworks!" in `cocoa pods` to be able to use

`#import <CleverTapReact / CleverTapReactManager.h>`

a compilation error is generated in UMLCore

> 1. Already make the link of the application with clevertap
> 2. Install all the package throught "yarn install"
> 3. Install the pods throught "pod install"

This is my podfile:

```
//----

target 'discovery' do
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
    'Core',
    'CxxBridge',
    'DevSupport',
    'RCTText',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTWebSocket',
    'RCTAnimation',
    'RCTImage',
  ]

  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'
  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
  pod 'CleverTap-iOS-SDK'
  pod "Segment-CleverTap"

  use_unimodules!
  use_frameworks!

  target 'discoveryTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end

//----
```

I expect a good compilation for the app, and instead im getting a compilation error

this is the error code:

```
//----


info Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_UMLogError", referenced from:
      +[UMUtilities NSDate:] in UMUtilities.o
      -[UMViewManager updateProp:withValue:onView:] in UMViewManager.o

info   "_UMLogInfo", referenced from:
      +[UMUtilities UIColor:] in UMUtilities.o

info   "_UMLogWarn", referenced from:
      -[UMModuleRegistry registerExportedModule:] in UMModuleRegistry.o
      -[UMModuleRegistry registerViewManager:] in UMModuleRegistry.o
      -[UMModuleRegistry registerSingletonModule:] in UMModuleRegistry.o
      -[UMModuleRegistryProvider moduleRegistryForExperienceId:] in UMModuleRegistryProvider.o
      -[UMViewManager updateProp:withValue:onView:] in UMViewManager.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

info clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


//----
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you're integrating CleverTap React Native using Cocoapods for your iOS Application and in my understanding issue is that you're unable to find the **CleverTapReactManager.h** class.

I would suggest adding `pod 'clevertap-react-native', :path => '../node_modules/clevertap-react-native'` as a dependency in your ios/Podfile instead of `pod 'CleverTap-iOS-SDK'`

This local **clevertap-react-native** Podspec integrate the React Native iOS bridge via Cocoapods.

Helping link to install the same: https://github.com/CleverTap/clevertap-react-native/blob/master/docs/install.md#installing-clevertap-react-native

Hope this helps. For further questions, you can post on https://community.clevertap.com/

Comment: Thanks Aditi, I tried that approach but in that scenario and without the use_frameworks! I get the error
/node_modules/clevertap-react-native/ios/CleverTapReact/CleverTapReactManager.m:9:9: fatal error: 'CleverTapSDK/CleverTap.h' file not found
#import <CleverTapSDK/CleverTap.h>

Comment: CleverTapSDK is a dynamic framework, by specifying **use_frameworks!** you can make CocoaPods integrate to your project via frameworks instead of static libraries. Therefore I suggest try including **use_framework!** in the pod file and then build your project.

Comment: Hi Aditi thanks for the answer but the thing is if we use that approach we get the error  ../../../ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:1:9: fatal error: 'FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found
#import <FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h> and that happens basically because we are using Firebase in order to set up google analytics and Firebase is not compatible with use_frameworks! [RNFirebase doesn't compile with use_frameworks!](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/252)

Answer (score 2):

or while importing in Appdelegate file , instead of

```
#import <<CleverTapReact/CleverTap.h>
#import <CleverTapReact/CleverTapReactManager.h>
```

use

```
#import <CleverTapReactManager.h>
#import <CleverTap.h>
```